# How to add a floating button at application level in Android

Tags: android

I am using Zoom Meeting SDK(.aar) in my app. When I start meeting from my app it will launch Zoom Meeting SDK and this SDK will take control and start the meeting, to start the meeting SDK have its own UI which I cannot control from my app. Now in the middle of meeting if I want to invite. To do this there is no option in SDK so I have to send Meeting ID to the other person.
If I can make it possible to add a floating button on the top of Zoom SDK Screen or Activity then it will be easy for me.

Comment: are you adding Zoom Meeting SDK UI to any of your layout XML?

Comment: no i am not adding. i am just initializing SDK